# Inserting an id into a div using Prototype/JS

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

Is it possible to insert an id into a div using prototype/javascript?
Basically:

```
<div> Hello </div>
```

should become:

```
<div id="myId"> Hello </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but without more code it's going to be tough to do because you have no way of identifying that `<div>` as it currently is coded. If it followed a `<div>` with and ID of `somediv` then you could do:

```
$$('#somediv > div')[0].setAttribute('id', 'myId');
```

Comment: there is another div that encloses about 15 smaller divs that i want to add ids too. Would that be possible?

Comment: I don't see why not. You could just loop through each div and add the id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("somelement").writeAttribute("id","myid");
```